# Constructing optimal Hamilton cycles from optimal Hamilton paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, heuristics, hamiltonian-paths, traveling-salesman-problem

> **Question:**
>
> can the shortest Hamilton cycle in a complete symmetric graph with weighted edges be constructed from the shortest Hamilton path in the same graph by connecting its ends and then exchanging pairs of non-optimal edges in the order they are encountered when traversing the Hamilton path?

Comment: What kind of edge exchanges are allowed?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen any kind of exchanges are allowed; I wonder however whether chained 2-opt moves suffice for finding the optimal tour...

Comment: Any kind of exchanges of *two* edges $ab$ and $cd$ into $ad$ and $bc$? (If you allow "any" exchange of any number of edges to any other edges, surely you find the optimum in one such exchange.) Also, between two vertices, can the edges in opposite directions have different weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the nine-vertex weighted graph in the figure (left). All edges have the same weight in either direction. Edges not shown are given a high weight, say, $10^6$.

[image: 9-vertex weighted graph]

The minimum-weight Hamiltonian path has weight zero (shown in the middle). Connecting its ends, you obtain a Hamiltonian circuit of weight $99$. Any swap of two edges $(a,b),(c,d)$ into $(a,d),(c,b)$ would only increase the weight.

However, the minimum-weight Hamiltonian circuit has weight $3$ (on the right).

Note that here an exhaustive search over *triples* of edges would find the optimum in one move. However, a similar construction with *four* chords would require finding an exchange of four edges (and the same idea can be extended arbitrarily).

Comment: nice counter example for the general case. It would be interesting to learn about the situation for metric graphs or for embeddings in the euclidean plane.

Comment: You can make the graph metric by adding $M$ to each edge weight, where $M$ is the maximum weight in the original graph. The situation with the Hamiltonian paths and circuits does not change. And of course any metric on $n$ points could be embedded as a Euclidean metric in $n-1$ dimensions.

Comment: What happens in low-dimensional Euclidean spaces, I have no idea. I hear they are cool places to live in.